# PHP parent:: not working?

Tags: php, oop

Why is the following code returning NULL? I am trying to get the parent method to return a value of a property inside the parent class but for some reason it is returning null.

```
class A {
    public $greeting;

    public function __construct($message){
        $this->greeting = $message;
    }

    public function getGreeting(){
        print 1;
        return $this->greeting;
    }
}

class B extends A{

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function getGreetingMessage(){
        parent::getGreeting();
    }
}

$classA = new A('Hello world');
$classB = new B();

var_dump($classB->getGreetingMessage());
```

In the parent method "1" is being printed so I know the method is being called

Comment: `return parent::getGreeting();`

Comment: You never call the parent's constructor so it will never be set

Answer (score 2):

Because the greeting message is not set in class b. so greeting message returns null.

Answer (score 1):

1) `return parent::getGreeting();`

2) `$classA` and `$classB` are different instances. Whatever you set in `$classA` is not accessible in `$classB`

3) constuctor of the parent is not called from `classB` and, moreover, you do not provide any arguments in initialization of `classB` (look at 2) above)

```
class A {
    public $greeting;

    public function __construct($message){
        $this->greeting = $message;
    }

    public function getGreeting(){
        print 1;
        return $this->greeting;
    }
}

class B extends A{

    public function __construct($message){
        parent::__construct($message);
        // or $this->greeting = $message;
    }

    public function getGreetingMessage(){
        return parent::getGreeting();
    }
}

$classA = new A('Hello world');
$classB = new B('Hello world 2');

var_dump($classB->getGreetingMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the parent's constructor in the child class, otherwise the parent constructor is not run and the class isn't properly initialized:

```
class B extends A{

    public function __construct($message){
        parent::__construct($message);
    }
```

So you most likely want this

```
$classB=new B('Hello World');
```

Comment: Or just don't override `__construct()` if you don't have anything to add to it.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, this is probably about to be very noobish, in PHP can you not inherit class properties that are initialized what so ever?

Comment: you still inherit the property, but your parent constructor, which gives the property a value, was never run, so you inherited the property, it was just null.